# Bottoms of the page do not match across pages

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two pages that use the same css but seem to look different.
Here they are:

```
128.48.204.195:3000
128.48.204.195:3000/formats
```

You can see that below the footer, the /formats file has no extra space, and the other file has about 50 pixels of extra space towards the bottom after the footer.  Do you know why that happens?  As far as I can tell, they use the same css.

Here is the css for the divs that I think are affecting this:

```
div#container
{
    width:70%; /* Controls the with of the page */
    margin: auto; 
  float: middle;
    text-align:center;
    /*padding: 1%;*/
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#eee;
}

div#header
{
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could actually post a working example. You will probably find people aren't willing to follow links to your development machine.

Comment: @Catfish just posted the css snippet in my question

Comment: @Wes You mean the screen shot?  Yeah probably that is what I will do next time.  But it also requires use of firebug so clicking on the link is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a min-height set on the `content` css class. Which is applied to your wrapper div. Remove or change the min height and it'll get rid of the extra space.

```
<div id="layout1" class="yui-t6 content">
```

Comment: thank you - in debugging this, how did you get to it?  I am trying to learn the most effective ways to debug such things.

Comment: Chrome developer tools. I right clicked, inspected the element, checked out the css rules that were applied to it, noticed it had the min-height, and changed that to 1em and it was fine. I had suspected it was something like that. Developer tools in Chrome are a life saver. Use Firebug if you use Firefox.

Comment: Use the firebug extension for firefox. Also, you have meta tags inside your body tag. They are supposed to be in the head tag.

Comment: @Catfish yeah I used Firebug but was not able to see that this particular css element was screwing up the page.  Also, what is the meta tag you are seeing inside the body?  I am missing something.  I don't see it.  - Thank you

Comment: If you view the source code, there are a couple of meta tags and lots of script tags that are inside your `<div id="header">` tag, but they should be inside your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
<div class="yui-t6 content" id="layout1">


       <h1><center>Welcome to the UDFR Project</center></h1>
    <p></p>
    <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
    <p>    
    </p>
    <p>
      User Id (testing MySQL call): 1

    </p>

    <p>


  </p><div id="footer">
     <hr>
     <center>Team | About Us | Purpose | How You Can Help | CDL </center>
  </div> <!-- End of footer --> 

</div>
```

The /formats page has no layout div, so it doesn't have all the same css rules applied. The css rule affecting the bottom part specifically is under .content {min-height: 20em;}
Change that to reduce the height.

As a side note, I think what you were going for is more like this:

```
    <h1><center>Welcome to the UDFR Project</center></h1>
<div class="yui-t6 content" id="layout1">
    <p></p>
    <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
    <p>    
    </p>
    <p>
      User Id (testing MySQL call): 1

    </p>

    <p>


  </p> 
</div>
<div id="footer">
     <hr>
     <center>Team | About Us | Purpose | How You Can Help | CDL </center>
  </div> <!-- End of footer --> 

</div>
```

Moving the content stuff in between the header and footer rather than containing them.